# Reading simple structures from a binary file and displaying specific data on the screen in c

Tags: c, structure, binaryfiles, fwrite, fread

I'm a newbie to programming and I am coding my first project. Part of my project requires asking the user for day, month and year; writing the note in the file and then displaying the corresponding note to the month and year on the screen. 
Here is my structure for notes:

```
typedef struct event{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    char title[20];
    char text[400];
} Note;
```

and here is the part related to the input:

```
fptr = fopen("note.bin","wb");
printf("\n\n\t\tAdd title:\n");
fgets(tempNote.title, 20, stdin);
fwrite(&tempNote.title, sizeof(tempNote.title), 1, fptr);
fseek(fptr, sizeof(Note), SEEK_CUR);
printf("\n\n\t\tAdd your note:\n");
fgets(tempNote.text, 400, stdin);
fwrite(&tempNote.text, sizeof(tempNote.text), 1, fptr);
fclose(fptr);
```

and finally the part that is responsible for reading and displaying data based on the given month and year:

```
fptr = fopen("note.bin","rb");
int len = 0;
while(1)
{
    fread(&tempNote, sizeof(Note), 1, fptr);
    if(feof(fptr) != 0) break;
    if(tempNote.month == month && tempNote.year == year)
    {
        len++;
    }
}
fclose(fptr);
for( int i = 0; i <= len ; i++)
{
    printf("\nYOUR NOTE %d\n",i);
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%s\t%s",noteCollection[i].day, noteCollection[i].month, noteCollection[i].year, noteCollection[i].title, noteCollection[i].text);
}
```

Once I run the program the output in the ending shows some garbage-like data.I tried reading the same questions but so far, I haven't managed to put my finger on the problem.
So what are the things that I'm missing??

Comment: Please make a [mcve] with sample input. (Giving sample input for a binary file is e.g. possible with a little part of the MCVE writing that binary file first). Explain in more detail what you are reading from and what you are writing to. Make sure you clarify when each is opened and closed.

Comment: If you have 3 notes you should read notes #0, #1, #2. Change `i<=len` to `i<len`

Comment: Writing and reading binary data like this is unportable; if you change anything in your environment (processor architecture, compiler version, compiler options, OS, ...) and recompile, you might not be able to read previously created files. This can be avoided by using a serialization library. Most of those are in C++ though, because it's easier to implement there.

Comment: Is it possible to post something more minimal that narrows down exactly which section of code is problematic?  You'll get the most responses this way.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

Your output function does something strange:

```
fwrite(&tempNote.title, sizeof(tempNote.title), 1, fptr);
fseek(fptr, sizeof(Note), SEEK_CUR);
fwrite(&tempNote.text, sizeof(tempNote.text), 1, fptr);
```

There is no need to `fseek()` after writing.  Instead, what I would do is to populate the entire `tempNote` first, then write it all at once:

```
fwrite(&tempNote, sizeof(tempNote), 1, fptr);
```

Then when reading it back, you can read the whole structure at once (or perhaps read repeatedly until you reach the end of the file).

Comment: It may be worth a note about serializing the output (writing the `strlen` of each `char text[400];` and then just the needed characters). While not necessary on this first project, at least having thought about the concept will be good for now. Writing `char text[400];` for every struct will produce a large file really quick (and needlessly if `text` holds something short like `"this is my description"`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: What you're saying is true, but I am just trying to get OP past the "It doesn't work at all" stage to "It works but maybe the file format can be optimized, though I probably don't care since it's a toy project."

Comment: The output was strange indeed. I ended up piling up entire`tempNote`into one and also did some adjustment about `len` in the for loop. Hopefully, they did the trick. Thanks for your time.